# .NET MVC routing using attributes only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Does anyone know how to create a route in .NET MVC which contains attributes only? My code is as follows:

```
[Route("{listingCategoryDescription}/")]
    public ActionResult CategorySearch(string listingCategoryDescription)
    {
```

As you can probably tell I want the URL to simply contain a category. Is this possible? Or do I need to hard code at least one part of the route?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the category passed in at the root URL? Like http://localhost/apples?

If so, this will work, but you will likely collide with other routes.

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    [Route("{listingCategoryDescription}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string listingCategoryDescription)
    {
        return Content("You picked category: " + listingCategoryDescription);
    }
}
```